# Distance between point and line in point slope form on a plane

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

If I have an equation in point slope form $$y=mx$$ how can I use the perpendicular distance formula:

$$\text{Perpendicular Distance} = \frac{\left | Ax_{1} + By_{1} + C\right |}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2} }$$

with my equation in point slope form knowing that this formula is designed for standard form?

Comment: The line eq. is generally $y=mx+c$ which you can write as $mx-y+c$ c.f. this with $Ax+Bc+C$, you will get your values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When given an equation in point slope form it is important to recognize that you can manipulate the equation to obtain values for A, B, and C and then use the perpendicular distance formula.

***y*=*mx***

subtract *y* from both sides in order to convert to standard form and get:

***mx - y* = 0.**

Now you can determine your A, B, and C.

**A=*m*; B=-1; C=0.**

Answer (score 0):

Convert to standard form.
$$y = mx$$

$$mx - y = 0$$

$$A = m; B = -1; C = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Then convert the equation to standard from. $y=mx$ is the same as $mx-y=0$ where $A=m$, $B=-1$, and $C=0$.